# Get specific DIV being scrolled

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

Let's say I have many dynamically created `div` with one class `box-comments`. Each of these `div` is scrollable. How would I go about detecting which `div` is being scrolled in order to trigger a specific event or function.

```html
<div class="user-content">

  <!-- this is dynamically created content -->
  <div id="box1" data-box="b1" class="box-comments">
    <button data-cmt="b1" class="get-cmts">more</button>
    <p>some content</p>
  </div>
  <div id="box2" data-box="b2" class="box-comments">
    <button data-cmt="b2" class="get-cmts">more</button>
    <p>some content</p>
  </div>
  
</div>
```

This is what I have so far but of course it's not working.

```js
$('.box-comments').bind('scroll', function(){
  var pos = $(this).scrollTop();
  if (pos == 0) {
    $(this).find('.get-cmts').trigger('click');
  }
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can make use of event object that is passed to the callback function as:

```js
$(".box-comments").bind("scroll", function(e) {
  // GET WHICH ELEMENT IS SCROLLING
  const dataBoxValue = e.target.dataset.box;
  console.log(dataBoxValue);

  var pos = $(this).scrollTop();
  if (pos == 0) {
    $(this).find(".get-cmts").trigger("click");
  }
});
```

```css
.box-comments {
  background-color: lightgray;
  height: 200px;
  overflow: auto;
  margin: 32px 16px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8" />
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge" />
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.7.0.min.js" integrity="sha256-2Pmvv0kuTBOenSvLm6bvfBSSHrUJ+3A7x6P5Ebd07/g=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <title>Static Template</title>
</head>

<body>
  <div id="box1" data-box="b1" class="box-comments">
    <button data-cmt="b1" class="get-cmts">more</button>
    <p>
      Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has
      survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop
      publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum. Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown
      printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release
      of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.
    </p>
  </div>
  <div id="box2" data-box="b2" class="box-comments">
    <button data-cmt="b2" class="get-cmts">more</button>
    <p>
      Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has
      survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop
      publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer
      took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset
      sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.
    </p>
  </div>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: @MaxNjoroge You want to know which div is getting scrolled, so you can get the information of the current scrolling div using event object

Comment: sorry I forgot to mention the box-comments div is dynamically created. I have edited my question

Comment: @MaxNjoroge Then all you have to do is after creating `box-comments` dynamically then you can add `scroll` event

Comment: could you please show how I would do that, my jquery is poor

Comment: okay I figured it out, adding it after it is declared worked thank you